# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'awsglue'

Tags: aws-glue

I have awscli version 2 installed and configured.
Trying to create an AWS Glue instance using the following code snippet:

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job

glueContext = GlueContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate())
```

This results in 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'awsglue''

Tried the same after installing 'fake-awsglue'. This further throws the following error -

```
from dynamicframe import DynamicFrame
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dynamicframe'
```

Can anyone suggest which library can be installed or any other way to overcome this issue ?

Thanks,
Amita

Answer (score 0):

please try to import this statement

```
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame
```